# Delegate change from child view to main view

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, childviewcontroller

I have UIViewController with mainView and ChildView.
I want change  label in mainView from ChildView

[image]

Child I add by

```
let to = ChildView()
self.addChild(to)
self.mainView.addSubview(to.view)
self.mainViewConstraint.constant = to.view.frame.height
to.view.frame = self.mainView.bounds
to.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

mainView - its view, where display childView

I'm try to do this with delegate
In ChildView:

```
protocol UserDelegate {
    func changeName(name: String)
}

class ChildView: UIViewController {

     var userDelegate: UserDelegate?

    @IBAction func changeNameBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.userDelegate?.changeName(name: "TestChanges")
    }
}
```

In MainView:

```
class MainView: UIViewController, UserDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let ChildView = ChildView()
        ChildView.userDelegate = self
    }

    func changeName(name: String) {
        self.helloLabel.text = "Hello \(name)!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you checked by adding breakpoint? your changename function triggering or not?

Comment: @ShauketSheikh , Yes Im checked - not triggering

Comment: it means something wrong with delegate. why you adding this? self.addChild(to)
after that you are adding in mainview. after that childview has two parent.

Comment: by the way your problem is here  let ChildView = ChildView()
your delegate is bind with this object and you are supposed to be called other objects delegate

Comment: @ShauketSheikh Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you present one instance of the `ChildView` and set a delegate on another instance of `ChildView`. So the child view that is presented on the screen is NOT the same one that calls the delegate. Set the delegate when you add the `ChildView`:

```
let to = ChildView()
self.addChild(to)
self.mainView.addSubview(to.view)
self.mainViewConstraint.constant = to.view.frame.height

// set the delegate here
to.userDelegate = self.mainView

to.view.frame = self.mainView.bounds
to.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

Moreover, to prevent retain cycles, use `weak` reference to the delegate:

```
protocol UserDelegate: AnyObject {
    func changeName(name: String)
}

class ChildView: UIViewController {

    weak var userDelegate: UserDelegate?

    @IBAction func changeNameBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.userDelegate?.changeName(name: "TestChanges")
    }
}
```

Finally, you can remove the `viewDidLoad` implementation from the main view:

```
class MainView: UIViewController, UserDelegate {
    // this should be enough
    func changeName(name: String) {
        self.helloLabel.text = "Hello \(name)!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Also in `MainView`, this `let ChildView = ChildView()
 ChildView.userDelegate = self` is unnecessary. Can be removed.

Comment: @Milan Nosáľ  Thank you!!